# Code sending double value, EF creating query with it the wrong way

Tags: c#, entity-framework, floating-point, double

I'm filling up an object that has a double.  In the database this field is a float.  My EF savechanges fails as it says it returns 0 records.

I have used sql profiler to see which query it sends to the database, and this query indeed fails, thus causing it to return 0 records.

So EF is right, but it send my float into a query in a way that makes the query crash.  Anyone has any idea why it does this? How I can avoid it?

This is my code object:

```
public partial class Rate : IRate
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string source_currency { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string target_currency { get; set; }

        public DateTime? date_l { get; set; }

        public double? rate_exchange { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

I put the double value into the rate_Exchange field in c# which works perfectly.  Upon inspecting the element using debugger it has the correct double value in there.

However EF sends it to the database formatted like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Rates]([CreatedOn], [source_currency], [target_currency], [date_l], [rate_exchange])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Rates]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity() AND [CreatedOn] = @0',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 varchar(3),@2 varchar(3),@3 datetime2(7),@4 float',@0='2023-02-08 15:58:58.0231618',@1='RUB',@2='EUR',@3='2023-02-01 00:00:00',@4=0,0132374518222941
```

obviously this fails cause it used a , instead of a . for the 4th parameter

any clues anyone?

Comment: Are you using a custom culture for your application? Try setting it to invariant.

Comment: read that solution somewhere, did not work at all.